# Calling javascript string function on browser from Unity returns null

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have a WebGL unity project which attempts to execute javascript code on the browser and return a value.

I have the following `.jslib` file in my Assets/Plugins/WebGL folder:

```
var BrowserPlugin = {
    GetEndpointURL: function()
    {
        var endpoint = window.itd.getEndpointUrl();

        console.log("endpoint: " + endpoint);

        return endpoint;
     }
};

mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, BrowserPlugin);
```

In my c# code in unity, I import the dll and call my javascript method like so:

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern string GetEndpointURL();

string endpointURL = GetEndpointURL();
```

The problem is, in my c# code the `endpointUrl` variable is always null.  However, in my browser console, I can clearly see the correct value is logged in the browser javascript before I return it.  What is causing this value to come back to unity as null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your code:

```
GetEndpointURL: function()
{
    var endpoint = window.itd.getEndpointUrl();
    console.log("endpoint: " + endpoint);
    return endpoint;
}
```

You **cannot** return string (`endpoint`) directly. You have to create a buffer to hold that string and this process includes allocating memory with `_malloc` and copying old string to that new memory location with `writeStringToMemory`.

```
GetEndpointURL: function()
{
    var endpoint = window.itd.getEndpointUrl();
    console.log("endpoint: " + endpoint);

    var buffer = _malloc(lengthBytesUTF8(endpoint) + 1);
    writeStringToMemory(endpoint, buffer);
    return buffer;
}
```