# Pass a callback from Unity to JavaScript and back to Unity

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I am trying to run an `Action` that sends data to the javascript on the browser, and when the browser finishes it runs a callback, and when the callback completes, it runs the item in the C# which runs the original callback.

Here are is the call order: `GameSmart.User.IsGuest(Action origCallback) -> IsGuestUser(/*Executes the javascript*/) -> GuestResponse(string json) -> origCallback()`

Once I compile and run the game, I get the following message in the chrome console:

> MarshalDirectiveException: Cannot marshal type 'GameSmart.Response`1<GameSmart.IsGuestResponse>'.

I am not sure what that is saying or even means. Is there something I am doing wrong?

This is the class **GameSmart.User**:

```
public class User : API {
  [DllImport("__Internal")]
  public static extern void IsGuestUser(Response<IsGuestResponse> response);

  [MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(Action))]
  public static void GuestResponse(Response<IsGuestResponse> r, string data) {
    r.callback(JsonUtility.FromJson<IsGuestResponse>(data));
  }

  public static void IsGuest(Action<IsGuestResponse> callback) {
    IsGuestUser(new Response<IsGuestResponse>(callback));
  }
}
```

Here are the **Response/Respond** classes:

```
public class Respond { }

public class Response<T> : Respond {
  public Action<T> callback;

  public Response(Action<T> cb) {
    callback = cb;
  }

  public void Action(Action act, params object[] args) {
    act();
  }

}
```

The JavaScript portion looks like this:

```
var GameSmartJs = {
  $GameSmartJs: {},

  IsGuestUser: function (obj) {
    gamesmart.user.isGuest(function (result) {
      this.runCallback('GuestResponse', obj, result);
    });
  },

  runCallback: function (callbackName, callback, result) {
    GameSmartJs[callbackName] = callback;
    Runtime.dynCall('vZ', callback, Pointer_stringify(result));
  }

};

autoAddDeps(GameSmartJs, '$GameSmartJs');
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, GameSmartJs);
```

**Edit**

As per @Programmer suggested, to use `_malloc` and `writeStringToMemory` I tried this, and it produces the same error message.

```
IsGuestUser: function (obj) {
  gamesmart.user.isGuest(function (result) {
    GameSmartUser.GuestResponse = obj;
    var buffer = _malloc(lengthBytesUTF8(result) + 1);
    writeStringToMemory(result, buffer);
    Runtime.dynCall('vZ', obj, buffer);
  });
},
```

Comment: Maybe you should use [`_malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41655066/3785314) and  [`writeStringToMemory`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41655066/3785314) before passing the string the parameter in the Javascript side. Not totally sure but you should try that.

Comment: @Programmer that didn't seem to work, I updated the question with what I tried.

Answer (score 3):

For the next soul that comes across this:

`Runtime.dynCall('vZ', obj, buffer);`

should be changed to

`Runtime.dynCall('vi', obj, [buffer]);`